# ASP.FormsAuthentication - Having two login pages

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I have two different login pages for two different sub-sections of my site.  I would like to declare two sets of defaultUrls and loginUrls for each login page/section.  Is this possible?  Does anybody have a code sample to do this?

I am securing both sections with similar code in the web.config files in each sections folder. Theoretically I would like to add to this config file where to go to login to this section.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="Administrator"/>
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but check out [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1348477.aspx) post.

Comment: Yup, that's what I was looking for.  Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with out of the box forms authentication unless you create two separate IIS applications for the two sub-sections of your site.